# Merge [pixel] and [pixels]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I'm not entirely sure why these are separate to begin with.

Description of [pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixel)

> In digital imaging, a pixel, pel, or picture element is a physical point in a raster image, or the smallest addressable element in an all points addressable display device; so it is the smallest controllable element of a picture represented on the screen. The address of a pixel corresponds to its physical coordinates. LCD pixels are manufactured in a two-dimensional grid, and are often represented using dots or squares, but CRT pixels correspond to their timing mechanisms and sweep rates.
>
> Each pixel is a sample of an original image; more samples typically provide more accurate representations of the original. The intensity of each pixel is variable. In color image systems, a color is typically represented by three or four component intensities such as red, green, and blue, or cyan, magenta, yellow, and black.
>
> In some contexts (such as descriptions of camera sensors), the term pixel is used to refer to a single scalar element of a multi-component representation (more precisely called a photosite in the camera sensor context, although the neologism sensel is sometimes used to describe the elements of a digital camera's sensor), while in others the term may refer to the entire set of such component intensities for a spatial position. In color systems that use chroma subsampling, the multi-component concept of a pixel can become difficult to apply, since the intensity measures for the different color components correspond to different spatial areas in such a representation.
>
> The word pixel is based on a contraction of pix ("pictures") and el (for "element"); similar formations with el for "element" include the words voxel and texel.

And of [pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixels)

> Each pixel has its own address. The address of a pixel corresponds to its coordinates. Pixels are normally arranged in a two-dimensional grid, and are often represented using dots or squares. Each pixel is a sample of an original image; more samples typically provide more accurate representations of the original. The intensity of each pixel is variable. In color image systems, a color is typically represented by three or four component intensities such as red, green, and blue, or cyan, magenta, yellow, and black.
>
> In some contexts (such as descriptions of camera sensors), the term pixel is used to refer to a single scalar element of a multi-component representation (more precisely called a photosite in the camera sensor context, although the neologism sensel is sometimes used to describe the elements of a digital camera's sensor), while in others the term may refer to the entire set of such component intensities for a spatial position. In color systems that use chroma subsampling, the multi-component concept of a pixel can become difficult to apply, since the intensity measures for the different color components correspond to different spatial areas in a such a representation.

Is it really necessary to have two tags that are basically the exact same thing? Sure, there's a *tiny* difference, but does that justify it?

A synonym is certainly an option, but which one is preferred? [pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixel) is currently favored 2:1 by question volume.

Comment: It just doesn't matter.  Everybody knows what a pixel is, their ability to select the right experts for the question compares unfavorably to zero.  Okay as a contextual tag, not a great one.  It is best not to ask SO users to vote on things that don't matter.

Comment: Wow, 50 followers on the pixel tag. Anyone got a pixel gold badge? ;)

Comment: I think this should be a burnination request for both of those tags. It's impossible to be an expert in pixels, and it gives no extra context when being added to the question.